# View child not working for Element Ref inside Modal -Angular

Tags: angular

#### I have a model which is a form and I am trying to pre-populate it. I think the element Ref of the Modal is not recognized by View Child and I am getting an issue something like this

```
core.js:5980 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'setValue' of undefined
    at EditPostComponent.ngOnInit (edit-post.component.ts:22)
    at callHook (core.js:2486)
    at callHooks (core.js:2457)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.js:2408)
    at refreshView (core.js:9207)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.js:10312)
    at refreshView (core.js:9216)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:10358)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:8989)
    at refreshView (core.js:9242)
```

#### IS there any other way to target the element ref?

Component

```
export class EditPostComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('e') queryForm: NgForm;

  id: string;
  originalPost: Post;
  constructor(private usService: UsaService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.id = this.usService.editPost;
    this.originalPost = this.usService.getSinglePost(this.id);
    console.log(this.originalPost);
    this.queryForm.setValue({
      title1: 'Testing ',
      body1: 'This is body',
      postUrl1: 'http',
    });
  }

  editForm(form: NgForm) {
    console.log(form.value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ViewChild` by default resolve query after the first change detection runs, so You have two solutions to this problem

1. use `static` option in `ViewChild` (if you use angular 8 or higher)

```
@ViewChild('e', { static: true }) queryForm: NgForm;
```

2. use `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle instead of `ngOnInit` to set your values